# How to make a default values

Tags: powerbi, slicers

I have county names as dublin1, dublin2, dublin3 how to make a single default name as dublin to those values in power bi?

I have tried to remove duplicates but it is not a correct solution. I have tried concatenate as well but it will be useful to merge columns.

I got the Solution for Above question, I have one more query, Please find below table, first column is I am having data like that, second column which i need data like that.

| Address 1: County | Cuounty |
| --- | --- |
| Dublin | Dublin |
| Co. Westmeath | Westmeath |
| Co. Kerry | Kerry |
| Dublin 13 | Dublin |
| Co. Dublin | Dublin |
| Dublin 6W | Dublin |
| Co. Longford | Longford |

Comment: Update your question with a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/) together with what the result you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a Table similar to:

| County | County Variation |
| --- | --- |
| Dublin | dublin1 |
| Dublin | dublin2 |
| Dublin | dublin3 |

You would then add a relationship on the second column to your data table(s). Lastly, you'd use the first column for your slicer.

In PowerQuery, you could add a Custom Column with:

```
Text.Proper(Text.Remove([Your Column], {"0".."9"} ))
```

[image]

---

Following on from the comments with additional asks. You can use this expression which will split the string by any of the following: `. 0123456789`, and return the longest portion.

```
Text.Proper(
 List.Last(
  List.Sort(
   Text.SplitAny([County Variation], ". 0123456789"),
   (x, y) => Value.Compare(Text.Length(x), Text.Length(y))
  )
 )
)
```

Version 2 to handle "Codublin":

```
let
  txt = Text.Trim(Text.Lower([#"Address 1: County"])),
  checkCo = if not Text.StartsWith(txt, "cork") and Text.StartsWith(txt, "co") then Text.AfterDelimiter(txt, "co") else txt,
  result = Text.Proper(
    List.Last(
    List.Sort(
     Text.SplitAny(checkCo, ". 0123456789"),
     (x, y) => Value.Compare(Text.Length(x), Text.Length(y))
    )
   )
  )
in
  result
```

[image]

Ideally, you would have a finite list of County names, then loop through and match based on containing that name.

Comment: I am getting data from Data verse, how can i create a table like this.

Comment: In your Power BI, Direct Query or Import from the Data Verse?

Comment: am creating data flows from data verse then i am connecting those data flows to power bi

Comment: You can create a table like that in Power BI Power Query. How many other County Variations do you have? Do they all have a number at the end?

Comment: Yes, i am having numbers for each county but i need only default value for those.

Comment: I've added a PQ Expression for a Custom Column in the answer above.

Comment: I am unable to use PQ expression, could you please help me out how to use. Am getting error while using.

I have one more doubt like, i have 2000 CRM URL's how to export those into power bi .

Comment: Added a snip to the answer above.

Comment: It is working fine now, Thank You So much, few counties are having extra alphabets like starting CO. or ending with some other extra alphabets. Could you please help me out with this as well.

Comment: Give some example of those (full examples).

Comment: Few Counties are perfect but few counties are like CO.Dublin, CO.Wormsmith, Dublin W, So i don't want CO. and extra letters after the county name.

Comment: Do you have a finite list of the County names?

Comment: no, I have to make changes in existing column and need to make a final list

Comment: See addition to the answer above.

Comment: Not working am getting all blanks except Dublin county

Comment: Updated answer to include `Text.Trim` as you may of had leading/trailing spaces.

Comment: Not working this as well

Comment: Update the question with a sample table in [markdown format](https://tabletomarkdown.com/). Alternatively, revert to the first answer and then leverage Power Query features like: [Replace Values in Power Query M](https://gorilla.bi/power-query/replace-values/). I believe I have answered your initial question.

Comment: Thank You So much @Sam Nseir to resolve the first question.. I have updated the question, could you please help me out.

Comment: Try the updated bottom expression.

Comment: Thank You so much for your help. Simply superb solution.

Comment: It is Working Fine but still am getting few county's like "Codublin". Is there any update on above query to remove these.

Comment: See version 2 above in the updated answer.

Comment: am getting syntax error while using version 2

Comment: Check if `[#"Address 1: County"]` is the right column name. Replace it with the right one in the right-hand list.

Comment: after update correct column also getting syntax error

Comment: Share a snip/screengrab of the expression with the syntax error. What does it say?